# readers-/writers multithreading in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, stdthread

I'm trying to implement a readers writers solution in C++ with std::thread.

I create several reader-threads that run in an infinite loop, pausing for some time in between each read access. I tried to recreate the algorithm presented in Tanenbaum's book of Operating Systems:

```
    rc_mtx.lock(); // lock for incrementing readcount
    read_count += 1;
    if (read_count == 1) // if this is the first reader
        db_mtx.lock(); // then make a lock on the database
    rc_mtx.unlock();

    cell_value = data_base[cell_number]; // read data from database
    rc_mtx.lock();
    read_count -= 1; // when finished 'sign this reader off'
    if (read_count == 0) // if this was the last one
        db_mtx.unlock(); // release the lock on the database mutex
    rc_mtx.unlock();
```

Of course, the problem is that the thread who might satisfy the condition of being the last reader (and therefore want to do the unlock) has never acquired the `db_mtx`.
I tried to open another 'mother' thread for the readers to take care of 
acquiring and releasing the mutex, but I go lost during the process.
If there is an elegant way to overcome this issue (thread might try to release a mutex that has never been acquired) in an elegant way I'd love to hear!

Comment: You are correct that the unlocking of a mutex is limited to the thread of execution that locked it or else it is undefined. I encourage you to rework this with `read_count` as an `std::atomic` which would block a writer unless its `0`

Comment: What actual behaviour are you trying to achieve? What contends for `db_mtx`, and why on earth are you thrashing two(!) mutexes to load a single value you never use?

Comment: If you can't use boost::shared_mutex, or C++14 shared_timed_mutex, you can have this one which has most of the implementation listed in the paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html#shared_mutex

Comment: @vu1p3n0x so the read_count would behave like a semaphore?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a condition variable to pause writers if readers are in progress, instead of using a separate lock.

```
// --- read code
rw_mtx.lock();    // will block if there is a write in progress
read_count += 1;  // announce intention to read
rw_mtx.unlock();
cell_value = data_base[cell_number];
rw_mtx.lock();
read_count -= 1;  // announce intention to read
if (read_count == 0) rw_write_q.notify_one();
rw_mtx.unlock();

// --- write code
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> rw_lock(rw_mtx);
write_count += 1;
rw_write_q.wait(rw_lock, []{return read_count == 0;});
data_base[cell_number] = cell_value;
write_count -= 1;
if (write_count > 0) rw_write_q.notify_one();
```

This implementation has a fairness issue, because new readers can cut in front of waiting writers. A completely fair implementation would probably involve a proper queue that would allow new readers to wait behind waiting writers, and new writers to wait behind any waiting readers.

In C++14, you can use a `shared_timed_mutex` instead of `mutex` to achieve multiple readers/single writer access.

```
// --- read code
std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> read_lock(rw_mtx);
cell_value = data_base[cell_number];

// --- write code
std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> write_lock(rw_mtx);
data_base[cell_number] = cell_value;
```

There will likely be a plain `shared_mutex` implementation in the next C++ standard (probably C++17).

Comment: thanks! I did not know this kind of mutex. Is the unique_lock / shared_lock constructor responsible for acquiring the rw_mutex or do I have to call a function like: lock() / unlock() ?

Comment: Yes. The `*_lock` helpers perform RAII lock/unlock for you. You can do `read_lock.unlock()` if you want to manually change the lock state.

Comment: @jxh If you haven't seen it: [Readers Writers locks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72642767/7582247) in which OP questions this solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the heads up. I have added an answer.